# Confused about DatagridviewRow

Tags: c#

I am trying to retrieve some data from a database and bind them to a `DatagridviewView` control I have added.
The problem is when I execute the code I am getting this exception:

> Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound.

I have noticed that columns are appearing twice when the program runs.
Could this be the reason for the exception? When I set the `AutoGenerateColumns` property to `false` instead, nothing will display.

What am I doing wrong?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=.\\sqlexpress;database=Projects;User Id=sa;Password=1234");
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from info",con);
    adp.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
    {
        int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item["Id"].ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item["Name"].ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item["Code"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, since you using `DataSource` property to bind data, you can't add data programmatically to your `dataGridView1`. You can add these data to your `dt` instead of directly your `DataGridView`.

Comment: Is this a Question about Rows or about Columns? Be clear about that.